# okhttp alternative container

Tags: android, okhttp

Ok I ma having problem with understanding okhttp. all I need is to upload an image to server.

[image]

this image is screenshot from my android studio , it seems I cannot `import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;` what is alternative container then ?

and as you noticed `.open(url)` is also red it is saying `cannot resolve java.net.url`

this is my full code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String str_url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    String reply_str = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption",caption));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("categorie",categorie));
    try {
        URL url = new URL(str_url);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        HttpURLConnection con = client.open(url);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(getEncodedParams(params));
        writer.flush();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reply_str = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object. There are better ways to parse data.
    JSONObject jObj;
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(reply_str);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;
}

//in this case it's NameValuePair, but you can use any container
public String getEncodedParams(List<NameValuePair> params) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (NameValuePair nvp : params) {
        String key = nvp.getName();
        String param_value = nvp.getValue();
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = URLEncoder.encode(param_value, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.append(key + "=" + value);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Use HashMap or JSONObject instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `BasicNameValuePair` you can use a [Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html)

the equivalent for `getKey()` would be `pair.first`. The one for getValue() would be `pair.second`

Comment: What about client.open(url) ? Why i am getting error

Comment: `OkHttpClient` has no member called `open`. It is also strange that this `open` method should return an HttpUrlConnection object.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest that you refer to the following for the alternative of `NameValuePair`:

```
    ...
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("key1", "value1");
                jsonObject.put("key2", "value2");
                jsonObject.put("key3", "value3");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonObject.toString());
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://...")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                        // do something...
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                        // do something...
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, just for some small testing projects :)

Comment: oh thats good man good luck and thank you for helping me. I work android in my part time alone and its annoying bcz I work in database(oracle) but I am trying to improve my self with androids when I have free time

Comment: hi man can you please help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089581/what-is-the-reasong-of-this-error-java-io-ioexception-content-length-and-stream? there probelm in the execution