# code not continueing to onpostexecute

Tags: android

I am not able to access `onpostexecute` can you  know why ? I got this `Log.d("e", "response.");` in my system log then it continue to another activity. I am not having any error.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

String myJSON;
JSONArray peoples = null;
InputStream inputStream = null;

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
    Log.d("e", Fetch_URL);

    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    builder.url(Fetch_URL);

    Request request = builder.build();

    String result = null;
    try {

      //  int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        //  int statusCode =200;

       // HttpEntity entity = response.body().byteStream();
     //   if (statusCode == 200) {
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            resulta = 1; //"Success
            Log.d("e", "response.");
          //  return response.body().bytes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("e", "r2r2 error");
        e.printStackTrace();        }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if( resulta ==1){
        myJSON=result;
        showList();
    }
    else{
        Log.e("d","zzzzzzzz");

    }
}
```

Comment: if you add `@Override` above onPostExecute, do you have compile time errors ?

Comment: @MD it is not a must.

Comment: Your Result type doesn't match the `onPostExecute()` signature, so it's not being called.

Comment: @Blackbelt yes method does not override subclass

Comment: you got your answer then.

Comment: @MikeM. `null` is a valid value for a String

Comment: @MikeM. I am returning null, what should I return ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns That's true, but `doInBackground()` returns a `byte[]`.

Comment: @MikeM. ah I hadn't noticed

Comment: you are returning byte array in doInBackground and you are taking string in onPostExecute comment your onPostExecute code and add new onPostExecute method and this type try to add this from suggestion it will create a method according to your requirements

Comment: @Moudiz Returning null is fine. You just need to get your types to match. Either change the Result type to `String`, or change the `onPostExecute()` method parameter type to `byte[]`.

Comment: @MikeM. should I return response?

Comment: @Moudiz Null is perfectly fine, unless you need to return a value. Just get your types sorted out, and you should be good.

Comment: @mike m. You were helpful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> method does not override subclass –

The  signature of your `onPostExecute` doesn't match the generic `Result` parameter of your AsyncTask subclass. Here

```
AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

`Result` is the type of the result of the background computation. Since your method has a `String` as parameter, you have to be consistent, and replace whatever you declared with `String`.

Comment: As awalys ur answers are helpful thanks, i have changed return to string result and i changed byte[] to string