# object() in object cannot be applied while creating adapter image

Tags: android

I am creating an adapter image and I am having this 2 errors:

[image]

this is the code

```
public class GridViewAdapter {

    private Context mcontext;
    private int layoutResourceId;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Listitem> listitem) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mcontext =context;

    }
```

this is second error

`cannot resolve method getitem()`

```
   ` Listitem item = getItem(position);`

if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Listitem item = getItem(position);
```

Comment: I think @Blackbelt answer is working for you. Moreover, you can read my answer at the following for reference when needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047156/how-to-create-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextview/33049491#33049491

Comment: thanks man ill check  it

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten my answer at one of your previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942144/all-images-not-displaying-from-the-same-url `public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>` :)

Comment: @BNK yes thank for reminding me about your answer. i Will look at it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`super` try to invoke the `super class`. You are   extending nothing, so implicitly, you are inheriting from `Object` which, in turn, has no such constructor (a constructor that takes three parameters)

Change

```
public class GridViewAdapter {
```

with

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {
```

Comment: if you prefer to post this as another question I will but I am having error in calling the adapter `GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, Listitem);` the error is on `this`. I added Mainactivity.this didnt work. I am calling the adapter in okhttp class .. what should I replace with this ?

Comment: the first parameter is a Context object. Ask yourself is `this` a Context ?

Comment: @Moudiz Since you use okhttp in asynctask class, so instead of "this", you can use mContext = this, then use mContext in the constructor of your adapter, as in my answer link above

Comment: or if you are instantiating it in an innerclass, and the outer class is an Activity, you can use `NameActivity.this`. If the outer class is a Fragment you have to use `getActivity()`

Comment: @Blackbelt can you check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197213/styling-bottom-action-icon-postion-and-background-color

Answer (score 2):

As we know super in java is calling the extended class constructor and in your case it has no extended class.
Always remember that if no class is extended super calls the no arg constructor of Object class and object class has no constructor with three parameters.